# explicit operator bool not called inside lambda — MSVC bug?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, lambda

```
#include <functional>

struct T {
    explicit operator bool() { return true; }
};

int main() {
    T t;

    if(t) {} // OK

    auto l = [&]() {
        if (t) {} // Error
    };
}
```

MSVC's behaviour seems oddly inconsistent here; the only difference between the OK line and the Error line is that one is in a lambda. Is this a bug?

Comment: Full text of the error message, please?

Comment: Also, what compiler version, platform, and edition?

Comment: Compiler is from Visual Studio 2012 Express with the November CTP upgrade, and identifies itself as `Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 17.00.51025 for x86`

and it gives `error C2451: conditional expression of type 'T' is illegal
        No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called`

Comment: Thanks for supplying that.

Comment: I `enjoy` this **BUG** too... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this a bug?

Yes, definitely. There is nothing wrong in your program, the `bool` conversion operator shall be invoked in both cases.